# Is there a way to grab only a desired string from an object that contains an email? I need to catch only the string before the @

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I try to extract only the **username** from the **"userPrincipalName"** and then concatenate it into the call of Axios as a parameter.

**the "userPrincipalName" Contains email like this apple@foo.com** and i need to concatenate only the "**apple**" ( i mean that I need just the string before the "@")

i dont understand what is my mistake on my split ..?

this is my example :

```
getData = () => {
        const { userPrincipalName } = this.state.azureLoginObject;
        this.setState({ isLoading: true, data: [] })
        axios.get("https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums",{ userPrincipalName }.split('@')[0])
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    data: res.data
                });
                console.log(res.data);
            });
    }
```

Comment: Split should do it, what issue are you facing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149025/how-to-cut-only-the-banana-name-from-the-userprincipalname here you did not get the answer because it was answered in the comments.

Comment: Please post the result you got !

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using split method on object rather than on string. I have updated the. If doesnot helps you, can you please update the error.

```js
 axios.get("https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums", userPrincipalName.split('@')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that "userPrincipalName" contains email  "apple@foo.com" after

```
  const { userPrincipalName } = this.state.azureLoginObject;
```

you can use the userPrincipalName as it is instead of putting it in { }.

```
  axios.get("https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums",userPrincipalName.split('@')[0])
```